# HTML Input value changed by Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to change this HTML input's value

```
SCORE:<input id="playerScoreAnz" type="text" readonly value="0">
```

with an extern Javascript file. I wanted to put +1 to the var 'playerScore', every time I the function activates. After putting +1 to playerScore it should put it into the value in the HTML Input.
I tried many things but nothing worked...

```
document.forms[0].playerScoreAnz.value = playerScore;


playerScoreField.val(playerScore);
```

these are just two things I tried, but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happened? What errors were reported?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.onload = function(){
var playerScore = document.forms[0].playerScoreAnz.value;

playerScoreField.val(playerScore);
}
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: int in js? You probably meant var :).

Comment: @pax162 yes I did ;) Sry been doing C++

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
document.getElementById("playerScoreAnz").value = playerScore;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running the code on window load? Try this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XVRJs/2/):

html:

```
<form>
    SCORE:<input id="playerScoreAnz" type="text" value="0" />
    <button type="button" onclick="changeWithjQuery()">change with jquery</button>
</form>
```

js:

```
function changeWithjQuery(){
    $("#playerScoreAnz").val(5);
}
window.onload = function(){
document.forms[0].playerScoreAnz.value = 7;    
}
```